# How to make this boost::enable_if code compile (SFINAE)?

Tags: c++, boost, sfinae, enable-if

I'm puzzled why the following code that uses `boost::enable_if` doesn't compile. It checks if type `T` has a member function `hello` and calls it if that's the case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

// Has_hello<T>::value is true if T has a hello function.
template<typename T>
struct has_hello {
  typedef char yes[1];
  typedef char no [2];
  template <typename U> struct type_check;
  template <typename U> static yes &chk(type_check<char[sizeof(&U::hello)]> *);
  template <typename  > static no  &chk(...);
  static const bool value = sizeof(chk<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template<typename T>
void doSomething(T const& t,
                 typename boost::enable_if<typename has_hello<T>::value>::type* = 0
                 ) {
  return t.hello();
}

// Would need another doSomething` for types that don't have hello().

struct Foo {
  void hello() const {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  }
};

// This check is ok:
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(has_hello<Foo>::value);

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  doSomething<Foo>(foo);
}
```

I'm getting

```
no matching function for call to ‘doSomething(Foo&)
```

with `gcc 4.4.4`.

The static assert is ok, so `has_hello<Foo>::value` is indeed `true`. Am I using `boost::enable_if` wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First parameter for `boost::enable_if` must be a *type that contains* a static `bool` constant named `value`. What you need is `enable_if_c` template (note _c suffix) that takes a non-type `bool` parameter.

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T const& t,
                 typename boost::enable_if_c<has_hello<T>::value>::type* = 0
                 ) {
  return t.hello();
}
```

This [compiles and runs](http://ideone.com/HAclh) fine.

Also explained under [Paragraph 2 in boost docs.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html)

Comment: Ah thanks. And since `has_hello<T>` is a type I can just use `typename boost::enable_if< has_hello<T> >::type* = 0`. Even better.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
typename has_hello<T>::value
```

`has_hello<T>::value` is not a *type name*. It is value.

---

Not sure about `bost`, but the following works (`gcc 4.7 std=c++0x`):

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T const& t,
                 typename std::enable_if<has_hello<T>::value>::type* = 0
                 ) {
  return t.hello();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So far, i haven't used enable_if, but maybe

```
typename boost::enable_if<has_hello<T>>::type* = 0
```